# How to update object element in array in React State

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

The code below is what I'm trying to do update `main_id` and `sub_ids` in the state.

I got stuck here...

```js
const [state, setState] = useState({
  ids: [
    {
      main_id: null,
      sub_ids: []
    }
  ]
});

// this is what I've tried..
const handleState = index => (v) => {
  setState({ ...setState, ids: setState.ids.map((x,i) => (
    i === index ? {x.main_id: v.id, sub_ids: []})
  ))})
}
```

I'm using this function on the same component which means it adds in specific index of array with different object.

```js
<componentOne onChange ={handleState(k)} />
<componentTwo onChange={handlestate(k)} />
```

```js
state = {
  ids:[
    {
     main_id: v.id,
     sub_ids:[]
    },
    {
     main_id: v.id,
     sub_ids:[]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please show your entire components as a [mcve]. Note that `onChange` is going to call the handler with `event`, not `index`.

Comment: I am looping same components with array.map function and assign them index

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the code below:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  ids: [
    {
      main_id: null,
      sub_ids: []
    }
  ]
});

// this is what I've tried..
const handleState = index => (v) => {
  setState({ ...state, ids: state.ids.map((x, i) => (
    i === index ? { main_id: v.id, sub_ids: [] } : x
  ))})
}
```